# html5app development

Tags: ubuntu-sdk

I am trying to run the html5app created from ubuntu sdk. But it is showing a message in popup is "Could not find a launcher for this projecttype in path" you can also see in image.

[popup after clicking on run button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo5A9.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, running ubuntu-sdk with Ubuntu 14.04. The ReadMe file helped me figure out what was wrong. I first apt-get installed the applications they asked for testing, but I reckon this was not entirely necessary.

In my case, the [myhtml5project].desktop file, the file that is run, indicated `Exec=webapp-container --inspector ./www/index.html`. You have to run that command on your terminal and see what goes wrong. Actually, there was a missing library when running. 
Depending on your config, the ReadMe file advises to put instead : `Exec=ubuntu-html5-app-launcher $@ --www=www --inspector`. 
After another install (`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-html5-container`), the program started.

I hope that works.

Good luck and tell us if you managed eventually to overcome your problem.